# Error while trying to deploy my war on jboss-6.1.0.Final

Tags: java, war, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

When I am trying to deploy my war on jboss-6.1.0.Final It gives Follwoing error message on my ecllipse console

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///home/shekhar/connector/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1392786872203/deploy/mywar.war state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///home/shekhar/connector/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1392786872203/deploy/mywar.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1475) [:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1316) [:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) [:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:838) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "sun.proxy.$Proxy150.setElementType(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, sun/proxy/$Proxy150, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for interface javax/wsdl/extensions/ExtensibilityElement have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2416) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2726) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1676) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:715) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.SOAPBindingUtil.getProxy(SOAPBindingUtil.java:87) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:274) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.SOAPBindingUtil.createSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:426) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createSoapBinding(SoapBindingFactory.java:213) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(SoapBindingFactory.java:198) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractBindingFactory.java:97) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:339) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.createBindingInfo(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:166) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:251) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:147) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:148) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:183) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:407) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:314) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:62) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:238) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:481) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:112) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:110) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.internalDeploy(WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.java:123) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 69 more
```

When i am trying to deploy my war file on **Jboss eap 6.1** It runs fine but It gives java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization while trying to deploy my war file on **jboss-6.1.0** when exposing web services.Is there any issue with **jboss-6.1.0**. Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure this is JBoss EAP 6.1? The log output doesn't look like it is.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It was log of jboss-6.1.0.Final version of Jboss